# Can't install rails-assets-tether

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

When I try to install `rails-assets-tether`, I get an error.

```
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for http://rails-assets.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see http://------/ruby-ssl. To connect without using SSL, edit y
our Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

This is the part of my Gemfile:

```
# Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.1.0'
end
```

Changing `https` to `http` didn't work for me.

I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of this problem
https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550